# По конкретному номеру инвентаризации выводятся все результаты вместо одной, как исправить?

Tags: 1с

Написал такой код:

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ИнвентаризацияОСВывод()
    
Запрос = Новый Запрос;
Запрос.Текст = 
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка КАК Ссылка,
    |ИнвентаризацияОС.Номер КАК Номер,
    |ИнвентаризацияОС.ПодразделениеОрганизации КАК ПодразделениеОрганизации,
    |РегСведПерв.ИнвентарныйНомер КАК ИнвентарныйНомер
|ИЗ
    |Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС КАК ИнвентаризацияОС, РегистрСведений.ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчет.СрезПервых КАК РегСведПерв
|ГДЕ
    |ИнвентаризацияОС.ПодразделениеОрганизации = &ПодразделениеОрганизации
    |И РегСведПерв.ИнвентарныйНомер = &ИнвентарныйНомер";


Запрос.УстановитьПараметр(
    "ПодразделениеОрганизации",
    Справочники.ПодразделенияОрганизаций.НайтиПоНаименованию("ПринтерыИКО")
);

Запрос.УстановитьПараметр(
"ИнвентарныйНомер",
"1357"
);

РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();

ВыборкаДокументов = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();

Пока ВыборкаДокументов.Следующий() Цикл        
    Док = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
    Для каждого Стр из Док.ОС Цикл
        Сообщить(Стр.ОсновноеСредство);
    КонецЦикла;
КонецЦикла;    
КонецПроцедуры
```

Здесь мы выбираем конкретную организацию: `ПринтерыИКО` и конкретный инвентарный номер: `1357`. В результате выводятся все результаты, которые касаются организации `ПринтерыИКО`.

Как сделать так, чтобы вывелся только позиция по инвентарному номеру: `1357`?

*P.S. Инвентарный номер находится здесь: РегистрСведений.ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчет.СрезПервых*

Answer (score 2):

У вас в запросе нет связи по Основному средству. Поэтому и выводит все что попало в выборку. Используйте соединения(аналог JOIN из SQL). Также в запросе обращайтесь к табличной части документа, где содержится ОС

Пример:

```
ВЫБРАТЬ
 |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка КАК Ссылка,
 |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.Номер КАК Номер,
 |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.ПодразделениеОрганизации КАК ПодразделениеОрганизации,
 |РегСведПерв.ИнвентарныйНомер КАК ИнвентарныйНомер
|ИЗ
   |Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС КАК ИнвентаризацияОС,
     |ВНУТРЕННУУ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрСведений.ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчет.СрезПервых КАК РегСведПерв
     |ПО ИнвентаризацияОС.ОсновноеСредство = РегСведПерв.ОсновноеСредство
|ГДЕ
 |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.ПодразделениеОрганизации = &ПодразделениеОрганизации
 |И РегСведПерв.ИнвентарныйНомер = &ИнвентарныйНомер
```

Возможно для вашего варианта необходимо будет что то подправить. Но главное, работайте не с документом ИнвентаризацияОС а с его табличной частью.

Пример обработки результата запроса:

```
РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();
ВыборкаДокументов = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();

Пока ВыборкаДокументов.Следующий() Цикл        
    Сообщить("Инв. номер: " + ВыборкаДокументов.ИнвентарныйНомер);
КонецЦикла;
```

Comment: использовал ваш код, все равно выводятся все позиции внутри табличной части документа, но уже для одной организации (ПодразделениеОрганизации), до этого выводились для двух организаций с похожими именами. Как теперь исправить так, чтобы выводилась только одна позиция ОС, а не все?

Comment: еще заметил такой момент, если добавить поиск по основным средствам, то вот эти основные средства выводятся только в том случае, если ввести правильный вариант основного средства, т.е. по номеру `1357`.  Но все равно, выводятся все варианты из конкретной организации `ПринтерыИКО`, а не одна позиция, которая имеет номер `1357`. Как отсеять те позиции, которые не должны были вывестись?

Comment: @ВадимЧиркунов инвентарные номера не совпадают? А так что то не то. Сделайте запрос который возвращает ОС из регистра сведений по номеру, и посмотрите что он вернет. Документ не трогайте пока. Как получите ссылку на основное средство, тогда в запрос добавляйте документ и устанавливайте связь.

Comment: совпадает, просто выводятся и другие позиции из списка. Хорошо, сейчас попробую

Comment: В консоле регистр сведений возвращает то, что мне нужно, нужный номер, добавил и основное средство, тоже находит нужную:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gdTp.png

Comment: На всякий случай спрошу, может в коде выборки проблема?

`РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();

ВыборкаДокументов = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();

Пока ВыборкаДокументов.Следующий() Цикл        
    Док = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
 Для каждого Стр из Док.ОС Цикл 
  Сообщить(Стр.ОсновноеСредство); 
 КонецЦикла;
КонецЦикла;`

Comment: Да, в коде, вот это лишнее - Для каждого Стр из Док.ОС Цикл
Запрос сразу возвращает инв. номер. А вы в цикле получаете ссылку на документ и начинаете перебирать всю таблицу основных средств. Загоните финальный вариант запроса в консоль и посмотрите что он вернет. И пользуйтесь конструктором запросов.

Comment: Финальный вариант в консоли отлично прошло, как и мне нужно. А в коде немного не понял, написал такой вариант без `Для каждого Стр из Док.ОС Цикл`:
`Пока ВыборкаДокументов.Следующий() Цикл        
    Док = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
 Сообщить(Док.ОС.ОсновноеСредство);
КонецЦикла; ` 

Пишет что `Поле объекта не обнаружено (ОсновноеСредство)`

Comment: Это лишнее, дополнил предыдущий ответ.